# TensorFlow freeze_graph.py: The name 'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am currently trying to export a trained TensorFlow model as a ProtoBuf file to use it with the TensorFlow C++ API on Android. Therefore, I'm using the [`freeze_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) script.

I exported my model using `tf.train.write_graph`:

`tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, FLAGS.save_path, out_name, as_text=True)`

and I'm using a checkpoint saved with `tf.train.Saver`.

I invoke `freeze_graph.py` as described at the top of the script. After compiling, I run

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph \
--input_graph=<path_to_protobuf_file> \
--input_checkpoint=<model_name>.ckpt-10000 \
--output_graph=<output_protobuf_file_path> \
--output_node_names=dropout/mul_1
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'save/Const', does not exist in the graph.
```

As the error states I do not have a tensor `save/Const:0` in my exported model. However, the code of `freeze_graph.py` says that one can specify this tensor name by the flag `filename_tensor_name`. Unfortunately I cannot find any information on what this tensor should be and how to set it correctly for my model.

Can somebody tell my either how to produce a `save/Const:0` tensor in my exported ProtoBuf model or how to set the flag `filename_tensor_name` correctly?

Answer (score 6):

The `--filename_tensor_name` flag is used to specify the name of a placeholder tensor created when you construct a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) for your model.*

In your original program, you can print out the value of `saver.saver_def.filename_tensor_name` to get the value that you should pass for this flag. You may also want to print the value of `saver.saver_def.restore_op_name` to get a value for the `--restore_op_name` flag (since I suspect the default won't be correct for your graph).

Alternatively, the [`tf.train.SaverDef` protocol buffer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/91a70cbf1c627117b70a3d2dd4c612779369e293/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saver.proto) includes all of the information you need to reconstruct the relevant information for these flags. If you prefer, you can write `saver.saver_def` to a file, and pass the name of that file as the `--input_saver` flag to `freeze_graph.py`.

---

* The default name scope for a `tf.train.Saver` is `"save/"` and the placeholder is [actually a `tf.constant()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/91a70cbf1c627117b70a3d2dd4c612779369e293/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py#L609) whose name defaults to `"Const:0"`, which explains why the flag defaults to `"save/Const:0"`.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that error happened to me when I had code arranged like this:

```
sess = tf.Session()
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '', '/tmp/train.pbtxt')
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess.run(init)
```

It worked after I changed code layout like this:

```
# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()    
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '', '/tmp/train.pbtxt')
sess.run(init)
```

I'm not really sure why is that. @mrry could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: +1 Had the same issue, changed the lines order in the exactly same way as you wrote, solved the issue for me as well. Would love some clarification, too :)

Comment: Seems the `saver` needs to be outside of a `sess` to be used repeatedly in different sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Some follow-up on @Drag0's answer and why the new code layout fixed the error.

When calling `saver = tf.train.Saver()`, you add the different variables related to the `tf.train.Saver()` such as `'save/Const:0'` to the default graph.

In the first code arrangement the graph is saved before so without the `tf.train.Saver()` variables. In the second code arrangement it is saved after, so the operation `save/Const` will exist in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be problematic in latest freeze_graph.py as I could see these removed:

`del restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name  # Unused by updated loading code.`
[source:freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)

In earlier version, it was using restore_op to restore the model

`sess.run([restore_op_name], {filename_tensor_name: input_checkpoint})`

So, for previous version, if you are writing the graph in .pb file before instantiating saver op, it will problematic. eg.:

```
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, "./logs", "test2.pb", False)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, "./logs/hello_ck.ckpt", meta_graph_suffix='meta', write_meta_graph=True)
```

This is because graph won't have any save/restore op for restoration of model. To resolve it, write graph after saving the .ckpt file

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, "./logs/hello_ck.ckpt", meta_graph_suffix='meta', write_meta_graph=True)
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, "./logs", "test2.pb", False)
```

@mrry, please guide if I interpreted something wrong. I only recently started diving into tensorflow code.