# 'IndexError:' when loading saved Tensorflow graph to continue training

Tags: tensorflow

> **Summary**: I have a Training routine that attempts to reload a saved graph for continued training but instead produces an `IndexError: list index out of range` when I try to load the optimizer with `optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimizer")[0]`. I experienced several other errors along the way, but ultimately this is the one that had me stuck. I *finally* figured it out so I'll answer my own question in case it might help others.

The goal is simple: I spent 6+ hours training a model before saving it and now I would like to reload and train it some more. No matter what I do, however, I get an error.

I found a [very simple example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/4_Utils/save_restore_model.py) on Github that simply created a `saver = tf.train.Saver()` operator and then `saver.save(sess, model_path)` to save and `saver.restore(sess, model_path)` to load. When I attempt to do the same, I get `At least two variables have the same name: decode/decoder/dense/kernel/Adam_1`. I'm using the Adam optimizer so I'm guessing that's related to the problem. I resolve this issue using the approach below.

I know the model is good, because further down in my code (see bottom) I have a Prediction routine that loads the saved model and runs and input, and it works. It uses `loaded_graph = tf.Graph()` and then `loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')` plus `loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)` to load the model. It then does a bunch of `loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')` calls.

When I try this approach (you can see the commented code) the "two variables" problem goes away, but now I get a `TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'save/Const', does not exist in the graph.` [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43243601/852795) does a good job of explaining how to organize the code to avoid the `ValueError: cannot add op with name <my weights variable name>/Adam as that name is already used`, which I've done.

@mmry explains the TypeError over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39476154/852795), but I'm not understanding what he's saying and don't see how I can fix it.

I've spent the entire day moving things around and getting different errors, and I have run out of ideas. Help would be appreciated.

### This is the Training code:

```
import time

# Split data to training and validation sets
train_source = source_letter_ids[batch_size:]
train_target = target_letter_ids[batch_size:]
valid_source = source_letter_ids[:batch_size]
valid_target = target_letter_ids[:batch_size]
(valid_targets_batch, valid_sources_batch, valid_targets_lengths, valid_sources_lengths) = next(get_batches(valid_target, valid_source, batch_size,
                           source_letter_to_int['<PAD>'],
                           target_letter_to_int['<PAD>']))

if (len(source_sentences) > 10000):
    display_step = 100 # Check training loss after each of this many batches with large data
else:
    display_step = 20 # Check training loss after each of this many batches with small data

# loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
# loaded_graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# input_data = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
# targets = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('targets:0')
# lr = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('learning_rate:0')
# source_sequence_length = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('source_sequence_length:0')
# target_sequence_length = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('target_sequence_length:0')
# keep_prob = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')

# loader = tf.train.Saver()
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=train_graph) as sess:    
    start = time.time()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 

#     loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)
#     optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimization")[0]
#     gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
#     capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -5., 5.), var) for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
#     train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)  

    for epoch_i in range(1, epochs+1):
        for batch_i, (targets_batch, sources_batch, targets_lengths, sources_lengths) in enumerate(
                get_batches(train_target, train_source, batch_size,
                           source_letter_to_int['<PAD>'],
                           target_letter_to_int['<PAD>'])):

            # Training step
            _, loss = sess.run(
                [train_op, cost],
                {input_data: sources_batch,
                 targets: targets_batch,
                 lr: learning_rate,
                 target_sequence_length: targets_lengths,
                 source_sequence_length: sources_lengths,
                 keep_prob: keep_probability})

            # Debug message updating us on the status of the training
            if batch_i % display_step == 0 and batch_i > 0:

                # Calculate validation cost
                validation_loss = sess.run(
                [cost],
                {input_data: valid_sources_batch,
                 targets: valid_targets_batch,
                 lr: learning_rate,
                 target_sequence_length: valid_targets_lengths,
                 source_sequence_length: valid_sources_lengths,
                 keep_prob: 1.0})

                print('Epoch {:>3}/{} Batch {:>6}/{} Inputs (000) {:>7} - Loss: {:>6.3f}  - Validation loss: {:>6.3f}'
                      .format(epoch_i, epochs, batch_i, len(train_source) // batch_size, 
                              (((epoch_i - 1) * len(train_source)) + batch_i * batch_size) // 1000, 
                              loss, validation_loss[0]))

    # Save model
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint)

    # Print time spent training the model
    end = time.time()
    seconds = end - start
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    print('Model Trained in {}h:{}m:{}s and Saved'.format(int(h), int(m), int(s)))
```

### This is the key part of the Prediction code:

This code works, so I 'know' that the graph is being saved successfully.

```
loaded_graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
    # Load saved model
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
    loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)

    input_data = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    logits = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('predictions:0')
    source_sequence_length = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('source_sequence_length:0')
    target_sequence_length = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('target_sequence_length:0')
    keep_prob = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')

    #Multiply by batch_size to match the model's input parameters
    answer_logits = sess.run(logits, {input_data: [text]*batch_size, 
                                      target_sequence_length: [len(text)]*batch_size, 
                                      source_sequence_length: [len(text)]*batch_size,
                                      keep_prob: 1.0})[0]
```

### Update - Another try at Training code

Here's another crack at the training code, trying to follow a suggestion from @jie-zhou. This time the line `optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimization")[0]` gives me `IndexError: list index out of range`. That line only works when it's after `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` so I'm not seeing what I'm supposed to initialize.

```
import time

# Split data to training and validation sets
train_source = source_letter_ids[batch_size:]
train_target = target_letter_ids[batch_size:]
valid_source = source_letter_ids[:batch_size]
valid_target = target_letter_ids[:batch_size]
(valid_targets_batch, valid_sources_batch, valid_targets_lengths, valid_sources_lengths) = next(get_batches(valid_target, valid_source, batch_size,
                           source_letter_to_int['<PAD>'],
                           target_letter_to_int['<PAD>']))

if (len(source_sentences) > 10000):
    display_step = 100 # Check training loss after each of this many batches with large data
else:
    display_step = 20 # Check training loss after each of this many batches with small data

loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
loaded_graph = tf.get_default_graph()

input_data = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
targets = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('targets:0')
lr = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('learning_rate:0')
source_sequence_length = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('source_sequence_length:0')
target_sequence_length = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('target_sequence_length:0')
keep_prob = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')

with tf.Session(graph=train_graph) as sess:    
    start = time.time()
    sess.run(tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()))

    loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)
    optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimization")[0]
    gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
    capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -5., 5.), var) for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)  

    for epoch_i in range(1, epochs+1):
        for batch_i, (targets_batch, sources_batch, targets_lengths, sources_lengths) in enumerate(
                get_batches(train_target, train_source, batch_size,
                           source_letter_to_int['<PAD>'],
                           target_letter_to_int['<PAD>'])):

            # Training step
            _, loss = sess.run(
                [train_op, cost],
                {input_data: sources_batch,
                 targets: targets_batch,
                 lr: learning_rate,
                 target_sequence_length: targets_lengths,
                 source_sequence_length: sources_lengths,
                 keep_prob: keep_probability})

            # Debug message updating us on the status of the training
            if batch_i % display_step == 0 and batch_i > 0:

                # Calculate validation cost
                validation_loss = sess.run(
                [cost],
                {input_data: valid_sources_batch,
                 targets: valid_targets_batch,
                 lr: learning_rate,
                 target_sequence_length: valid_targets_lengths,
                 source_sequence_length: valid_sources_lengths,
                 keep_prob: 1.0})

                print('Epoch {:>3}/{} Batch {:>6}/{} Inputs (000) {:>7} - Loss: {:>6.3f}  - Validation loss: {:>6.3f}'
                      .format(epoch_i, epochs, batch_i, len(train_source) // batch_size, 
                              (((epoch_i - 1) * len(train_source)) + batch_i * batch_size) // 1000, 
                              loss, validation_loss[0]))

    # Save model
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint)

    # Print time spent training the model
    end = time.time()
    seconds = end - start
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    print('Model Trained in {}h:{}m:{}s and Saved'.format(int(h), int(m), int(s)))
```

### Update 2 - Yet another try at the Training code

Trying to follow [this model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43243601/852795) more closely, I've added code to check for the existence of a graph and do different things if I'm loading an existing graph. I also built it similar to the Prediction code, which I know works. One important different is that, unlike during Prediction, I need to load the optimizer for training.

It runs fine with a brand new graph, but it still unable to load an existing graph. I am still, however, getting `IndexError: list index out of range` at `optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimization")[0]`.

I've cut out some bits of code which are above to focus on the essential.

```
# Test to see if graph already exists
if os.path.exists(checkpoint + ".meta"):
    print("Reloading existing graph to continue training.")
    brand_new = False    
    train_graph = tf.Graph()
#     saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
#     train_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
else:
    print("Starting with new graph.")
    brand_new = True
    with train_graph.as_default():
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=train_graph) as sess:    
    start = time.time()
    if brand_new:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    else:
#         sess.run(tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())) 
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint) 

        # Restore variables
        input_data = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
        targets = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('targets:0')
        lr = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('learning_rate:0')
        source_sequence_length = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('source_sequence_length:0')
        target_sequence_length = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('target_sequence_length:0')
        keep_prob = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')

        # Load the optimizer
        # Commenting out this block gives 'ValueError: Operation name: "optimization/Adam"'
        # Leaving it gives 'IndexError: list index out of range' at 'optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimizer")[0]'
        optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimizer")[0]
        gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
        capped_gradients = [(tf.clip_by_value(grad, -5., 5.), var) for grad, var in gradients if grad is not None]
        train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(capped_gradients)  

    for epoch_i in range(1, epochs+1):
        for batch_i, (targets_batch, sources_batch, targets_lengths, sources_lengths) in enumerate(
                get_batches(train_target, train_source, batch_size,
                           source_letter_to_int['<PAD>'],
                           target_letter_to_int['<PAD>'])):

            # Training step
            _, loss = sess.run(...)

            # Debug message updating us on the status of the training
            if batch_i % display_step == 0 and batch_i > 0:

                # Calculate validation cost and output update to training

    # Save model
#     saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint)
```

Comment: I found `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) ` in your training code, technically adam optimizer relies on some `local variables` but you didn't initialize them, maybe you can have a try after initializing them.

Comment: Thank you, @Jie.Zhou. I've updated the post with another crack at the code. I initialize `input_data`, `targets`, etc., but I'm not seeing what I need to initialize for Adam. Could you please give me some details?

Comment: Change `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` into `sess.run(tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()))`, and futhermore, I noticed that you created two savers and you used the second saver to save model so the tensor should be `save_1/Const:0` not `save/Const:0`, maybe you should delete one of them.

Comment: Thank you. I've removed the comments because they were causing confusion. I only have 1 saver at the end, and a loader at the beginning. I changed `sess.run()` as you suggested (see above) and now `loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)` is giving me `TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'save/Const', does not exist in the graph`, which is back to the "original" error.

Comment: According to the post you mentioned ([Answer by Drag0][1])
`saver = tf.train.Saver()` should be before `sess = tf.Session()` and `tf.train.write_graph()`


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40788998

Comment: @MaosiChen Thank you. That post, which is difficult to follow, seems to be referring to _writing_ the graph, as opposed to reading it. Still, I moved around some of the code (again) and added another update (above). I'm still stuck at the `IndexError: list index out of range` at `optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimization")[0]`. Why is this so crazy hard?

Comment: I cannot _believe_ that I figured this out. Holy cow. When I build the graph I need to add `tf.add_to_collection("cost", cost)` & `tf.add_to_collection("train_op", train_op)` and then when I reload the graph I need to get them with `cost = tf.get_collection("cost")[0]` & `train_op = tf.get_collection("train_op")[0]`. I'm not sure why, but "optimizer" and "optimization" didn't exist. I'm exhausted. I need to go for a walk. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`optimizer = tf.get_collection("optimization")[0]` was throwing an `IndexError: list index out of range` when trying to restore the saved graph for the simple reason that it wasn't "named" when the graph was built and so there's nothing in the graphed called "optimizer".

The training step `_, loss = sess.run([train_op, cost], {input_data: sources_batch, targets: targets_batch, lr: learning_rate, target_sequence_length: targets_lengths, source_sequence_length: sources_lengths, keep_prob: keep_probability})` requires `input_data`, `targets`, `lr`, `target_sequence_length`, `source_sequence_length` and `keep_prob`. As can be seen, all of these are restored with this block of code:

```
    # Restore variables
    input_data = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    targets = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('targets:0')
    lr = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('learning_rate:0')
    source_sequence_length = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('source_sequence_length:0')
    target_sequence_length = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('target_sequence_length:0')
    keep_prob = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')
```

This works because when building the graph I "named" every one of these variables with something like `input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='input')`.

Additionally, however, the training step requires `train_op` and `cost`. (It's worth noting that it doesn't directly require `optimizer`. I noticed that and my naive attempt to generate `train_op` was not going to work.)

The solution, in the end, was pretty simple. At the point in my code where I build the graph, immediately after creating `train_op` and `cost` I run `tf.add_to_collection("train_op", train_op)` and `tf.add_to_collection("cost", cost)`. These statements "name" the operations in the graph, so I can get them later. Then, in the training routine, right after restoring the variables above, I run this:

```
    # Grab the optimizer variables that were added to the collection during build
    cost = tf.get_collection("cost")[0]
    train_op = tf.get_collection("train_op")[0]
```

Both of these now work, the saved graph is loaded, all the necessary variables and operations are identified and the training picks up from where it left off.